# less @import not working

Tags: css, web, less

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/news.less">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="less.js"></script>
</body>
```

news.less looks like this;

```
@import: "libs/base.less"
```

base.less looks like this;

```
@import "colors.less";
@import "mixins.less";
@import "bootstap.less";
@import "font-aweseome.less"

body {
    background-color: @light-grey;
}
```

bootstrap.less and font-awesome.less are CSS files with an altered extension. All the files are in the right folders.

When looking in the browser, styling in base.less is being ignored, meaning that my imports are not working.

Can anyone give any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: do you have this `less/libs/base.less` ?

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy - I do indeed.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Your `@import` statements must follow this format:

```
@import "styles.less";
```

`@import "font-aweseome.less"` isn't working because there is no semicolon at the end.

`@import: "libs/base.less"` won't work because there is a colon after the import statement.

Answer (score 4):

Why the colon in:

```
@import: "libs/base.less"
```

I think is better to have a semicolon after all @import-s.

Take a look in the console to make sure the paths are correct, and the browser isn't trying to load a less file from the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
@import url('Your Path');

Answer (score 0):

to import is

```
@import "styles.less";
```

Comment: Your answer is no different than the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

1.Import your base.less in news.less like,

```
    @import "libs/base.less";
```

2.Refer your news.less file in the html

```
    <link  rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css"  href="less/news.less"/>
```

3.Refer less.js library in the html

```
    <script src="lib/less.js"></script>
```